# Can I configure the QuickTest print log size limit beyond 1000 lines?

Tags: logging, vbscript, qtp

Most of us know that the Print statement outputs its string argument into the Quicktest print log, a scrollable text viewer which opens whenever something is printed into it.

**It seems to have a limit of 1000 lines.
Can I configure that somewhere?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the line limit isn't configurable.

The `Print` command is meant primarily in order to facilitate debugging tests using [`printf` debugging](http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/DebugCPP/Volume/techniques.html).

If you want to print more lines you can write a simple COM object that doesn't have this limit and use it from your script.

Comment: Addendum: The temp file folder contains QTPrintLog.txt. This is a log of all print messages, and it seems not to be purged at any time, so it holds more than the last 1000 lines, should someone be interested.